# Postgres insert into selct on conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, insert, postgresql-9.2

I would like to insert into a table values which come from another table without having duplicates.

I tried this way but i doesn't work for me..
could you please assist me to find the right query for this job.

```
insert into tab1(date_id, act_su) 
(select max( valid_date ) , count(*) from table2 where status = 'ACTIVE')
ON CONFLICT (date_id)
DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Could you show us the table definition for tab1 ? And the definition of "doesn't work for me", including code and error messages. And it will never work on version 9.2, that is EOL for a decade or so.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 did not have the `on conflict` option.

Comment: CREATE TABLE tab1(
 date_id timestamp NULL,
 act_su int8 NULL
)
DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY;

error message : SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON"

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative for my issue :

```
insert into tab1(date_id, act_su)  
select max( t2.valid_from ) , count(*) from table2 t2 
WHERE upper(t2.status) like 'ACTIVE%' 
and t2.valid_from not in (SELECT date_id FROM tab1 t1);
```